# Bring custom soft keyboard to font of custom dialog

Tags: java, android, dialog, keyboard

I'm trying to develop an Android app using in-app custom soft keyboard. So I followed this topic on xda-developers to make my own keyboard: [[GUIDE] The right Soft Keyboard (+adding a CustomKeyboard)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2497237)

Everything works fine in MainActivity, the only problem I faced is showing my custom keyboard for custom dialog. 
As you can see in the image below, when my dialog showing, it's above of custom keyboard, so I can't enter data into EditText inside dialog by custom keyboard.

I've tried some ways to bring custom keyboard to front of dialog, but nothing worked. 
For now, I'm using system soft keyboard to enter data inside dialog, but it makes my app inconsistent.

I hope anyone can help me solve this problem or give me some suggestions. 
Thanks for all!

Please see image here: [Photobucket](http://i1278.photobucket.com/albums/y518/rain10293/2014-09-03_230718_zpsf48d5767.jpg)

Comment: Did u find any answer?